How to I install jsonlib without getting errors in python/vscode? (beginner)
I, as a beginner to python, am trying to install jsonlib, but error messages keep popping up in the terminal. This message shows when trying to install jsonlib:
Collecting jsonlib
  Using cached jsonlib-1.6.1.tar.gz (43 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: jsonlib
  Building wheel for jsonlib (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for jsonlib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [55 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      copying jsonlib.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      running build_ext
      building '_jsonlib' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /Tc_jsonlib.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\_jsonlib.obj
      _jsonlib.c
      _jsonlib.c(98): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_AsUnicode': deprecated in 3.3
      _jsonlib.c(99): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_GetSize': deprecated in 3.3
      _jsonlib.c(310): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_FromUnicode': deprecated in 3.3
      _jsonlib.c(348): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_FromUnicode': deprecated in 3.3
      _jsonlib.c(396): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_FromUnicode': deprecated in 3.3
      _jsonlib.c(450): warning C4013: 'PyLong_FromUnicode' undefined; assuming extern returning int
      _jsonlib.c(450): warning C4047: '=': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
      _jsonlib.c(550): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
      _jsonlib.c(643): warning C4020: 'PyFloat_FromString': too many actual parameters
      _jsonlib.c(655): warning C4047: '=': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
      _jsonlib.c(638): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_FromUnicode': deprecated in 3.3
      _jsonlib.c(1186): warning C4013: 'PyString_CheckExact' undefined; assuming extern returning int
      _jsonlib.c(1188): warning C4013: 'PyString_Check' undefined; assuming extern returning int
      _jsonlib.c(1208): warning C4013: 'PyObject_Unicode' undefined; assuming extern returning int
      _jsonlib.c(1208): warning C4047: '=': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
      _jsonlib.c(1406): warning C4013: 'PyInt_CheckExact' undefined; assuming extern returning int
      _jsonlib.c(1466): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE': deprecated in 3.3
      _jsonlib.c(1467): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE': deprecated in 3.3
      _jsonlib.c(1517): warning C4013: 'PyString_AS_STRING' undefined; assuming extern returning int
      _jsonlib.c(1517): warning C4047: 'function': 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
      _jsonlib.c(1517): warning C4024: 'ascii_constant': different types for formal and actual parameter 1
      _jsonlib.c(1539): warning C4013: 'PyInt_Check' undefined; assuming extern returning int
      _jsonlib.c(1702): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE': deprecated in 3.3
      _jsonlib.c(1703): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE': deprecated in 3.3
      _jsonlib.c(1751): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_FromUnicode': deprecated in 3.3
      _jsonlib.c(1755): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE': deprecated in 3.3
      _jsonlib.c(1782): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE': deprecated in 3.3
      _jsonlib.c(1783): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE': deprecated in 3.3
      _jsonlib.c(1821): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_FromUnicode': deprecated in 3.3
      _jsonlib.c(1825): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE': deprecated in 3.3
      _jsonlib.c(1931): warning C4047: '=': 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
      _jsonlib.c(1970): warning C4047: 'function': 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
      _jsonlib.c(1970): warning C4024: 'serializer_append_ascii': different types for formal and actual parameter 2
      _jsonlib.c(2089): warning C4013: 'PyUnicode_Encode' undefined; assuming extern returning int
      _jsonlib.c(2089): warning C4047: '=': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
      _jsonlib.c(2095): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_FromUnicode': deprecated in 3.3
      _jsonlib.c(2123): warning C4047: '=': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
      _jsonlib.c(2129): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_FromUnicode': deprecated in 3.3
      _jsonlib.c(2161): warning C4013: 'Py_InitModule3' undefined; assuming extern returning int
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe" /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311 /LIBPATH:C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22621.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.22621.0\\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit__jsonlib build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\_jsonlib.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\_jsonlib.cp311-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\_jsonlib.cp311-win_amd64.lib
      LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyInit__jsonlib
      build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\_jsonlib.cp311-win_amd64.lib : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.39.33519\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1120
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for jsonlib
Failed to build jsonlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for jsonlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I have already verified that PIP is installed, I have updated redistributables and I have tried to update Visual Studio Build tools, as it said to do so in the error message before. I have ran the windows updater, just in case. This message now is new and I don't know what else to do,

Are you using Python 2? Python 3 ships with the json module built in. There's also a note on the jsonlib page that says "For the Python 3 version of jsonlib, see jsonlib-python3.". I might also point out that jsonlib hasn't been updated in 14 years (since 2010)...are you 100% sure it's what you need?

I'm following a tutorial where it says to install jsonlib. I figured I could just try to install it, since I thought it could do no harm. Can I check if it's already installed/built in? If I try to install turtle for example, it also gives me an error. Can I check which modules have been installed already?

Out of curiosity, which tutorial are you following? And yes, you can see which modules you've installed via pip by running the command pip list. Just bear in mind that pip list won't show you built-in modules (things like json, asyncio, tkinter, etc.)

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-track-iss-international-space-station-using-python/ This one. It doesn't seem to be that outdated, but I have found that json and webbrowser are indeed build in already. I am trying to learn python and I figured this was a nice starting project, while also customising the code myself.

I can't personally recommend that tutorial - many of the packages it suggests are built in to Python now and/or out of date. As you've noticed, jsonlib and webbrowser now have built-in equivalents, geocoder hasn't been updated since 2018, urllib is now also built-in, but even it's documentation recommends using the Requests package instead, and times is no longer maintained and has built-in replacements (time, datetime, etc.)

Thank you! I will search for something else then. Thanks for the quick response!

Sure thing! Good luck and happy coding. I will say, the project in that tutorial looks fun - it might be a good exercise to try getting it working with more modern Python.

I know that pip is already installed but a while ago i had a similar problem, i was using a virtual environment so may be a different situation, but for me worked this command that 'force reinstall' the pip library.  python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip.
